# how to get rid of the whitespace at the end?

Tags: python-3.x

i'm just a beginner to python and i have been asked to solve a problem where your program has to decode a code in which it takes every 3rd letter and puts them together with a gap in between each letter, sorry that was a bad explanation but have a look at my code:

```
    m=input("Message? ")
    for c in m[::3]:
      print(c,end=' ')
```

the problem is there's a whitespace after the last letter and i dont know how to get rid of it, i've tried .rstrip and that doesnt work. i've also tried to [::-1]after the end=' ' and that doesn't work.

Comment: If its the last letter then it doesnt matter if there is a space at the end of it?

Comment: the course requires there to be no last space left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem is exactly but I'm assuming you mean to say that on your last print you do not want the end=' ' whitespace. To produce the string you want you can join the slice on whitespace as [lltt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61742259/13522187) said, minus the redundant list comprehension.

```
m = "123456789"
print(" ".join(m[::3]))
```

Output:

```
"1 4 7"
```

If you really want to maintain your for loop print functionality you need a way to determine if you are in the last loop. This is a general problem which has various solutions such as a look-ahead function. But you can simply break up the for loop into two parts.

```
m="123456789"
for c in m[::3][:-1]:
    print(c,end=' ')
print(m[::3][-1], end='')
```

Output:

```
1 4 7
```

Of course you do not need the `end=''` in the last print; `print(m[::3][-1])` is fine. It is just there for readability.

If you mean to say that the decoded message cannot have a whitespace as the last character then you can use .rstrip(). For example when the last, third character of the input, is a whitespace.

```
m = "input with trailing whitespace "
print(" ".join(m[::3]))
```

Output:

```
"i u w h r l g h e a  "
```

Here you can chain the rstrip() method.

```
m = "input with trailing whitespace "
print(" ".join(m[::3]).rstrip())
```

Output:

```
"i u w h r l g h e a"
```

Comment: thank you for taking your time to answer this, the problem was that the course wouldn't let me finish if there was a whitespace at the end, this was an example they gave of how it should look:
Message? cxohawalkldflghemwnsegfaeap
"c h a l l e n g e"

however my programme was adding a whitespace after the last letter:
"c h a l l e n g e "
All of the above solutions worked, thanks to everyone else who helped. I haven't learnt about "join" yet but i have learnt about "strip" and "chopping(i think it's called)[:::]" and for loops so thats why i was trying to use those.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `str.join` on a list comprehension rather than a loop:

```
" ".join(m[::3])
```

This would put a space between each letter, excluding the trails.

Comment: There is no need for the list comprehension.

Comment: @DYZ Yes, but it better demonstrates the concept of inline looping for OP, since they/re a beginner.

Comment: Not sure why you say so. For a beginner, _not_ having a list comprehension is better than _having_ a list comprehension. Also, your example teaches bad programming practices.

Answer (score 0):

When working with strings, you should avoid hand-crafted solutions that are inefficient and often incorrect. Connect the letters with spaces using the string method `.join()`:

```
m = "Hello, world!"
print(" ".join(m[::3]))
#'H l w l'
```